# Invertible Matrices isomorphisms vs projections

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I'm self learning linear-algebra.

I'm having trouble understanding why if $A$ is a matrix where $F(x) = Ax$ is an orthogonal projection, it cannot be necessarily invertible.

Why is that the case, but when $A$ is a matrix such that $F(x) = Ax$ is an isomorphism, $A$ **is** necessarily invertible?

Comment: A matrix like $A=\pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&0}$ which projects $\Bbb R^3$ orthogonally onto a plane, perhaps?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown can you please clarify your statement?

Comment: Isomorphisms are invertible by definition

Comment: Just as an aside, here oh MSE you should mark an answer as accepted if you feel that it gave you what you were looking for. This not only gives credit to the user that wrote the answer, but it marks your post as closed to every other MSE user

Comment: @DavideMorgante. As you can tell, I'm a quite new user. How do I do that? 
Thank you for all your assistance

Comment: Don't worry! You should give a read to our community guidelines! To mark an answer as accepted just click on the $V$ beside the answer you want to accept

Comment: @DavideMorgante. Yes. Thank you for your fine help. I am very grateful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine you want to project all $\mathbb{R}^3$ onto a plane $\pi$: necessarily some points from $\mathbb{R}^3$ have to go to same points in $\pi$ (simply speaking there are too many points in $\mathbb{R}^3$, you have to squeeze $\mathbb{R}^3$ to become a plane), so this map cannot be invertible. Defining this map with a matrix $A$ means that the matrix cannot be invertible because you cannot map every point from $\pi$ from it's respective point, where they came from, in $\mathbb{R}^3$. The only thing you can say about a projection matrix is that if $A$ is a projection matrix, then it's *idempotent* ($A^2=A$). In fact if you take the same map as before and try to apply it to the plane $\pi$ it has to get you again to $\pi$. The only invertible projection is the identity, which can be easily proven with the fact that a projection is idempotent.

Conversely if $A$ is a matrix of an isomorphism, by definition an *isomorphism* is a map one-to-one, so it maps every point in the domain to **one and one only** point into the codomain. So if you want to come back from the codomain to the domain you don't have any choice  over taking a point from the codomain and making it come back from the point where it came from the first place. So an isomorphism is clearly invertible and then you can compute the inverse matrix $A^{-1}$ that gives you the inverse map

Comment: as a follow up question, how does one disprove that any symmetric matrix is invertible

Comment: I can give you a simple example $$\left[\begin{matrix}1&1\\1&1\end{matrix}\right]$$ is clearly symmetric but not invertible, in fact it's determinant is zero

Answer (score 1):

A projection (not even orthogonal) satisfies $A^2=A $. If $A $ is also invertible, you can multiply the equality by $A^{-1} $ to obtain $A=I $. In other words, the only invertible projection is the identity.

*Isomorphism*, on the other hand, implies that  $A $ is bijective, which is the same as invertible.